# How to read csv from ARGF

Tags: ruby, csv

In Ruby 1.9 how do I read CSV from ARGF?

I tried the following, but it printed nothing:

```
require 'csv'
CSV(ARGF).read do |row|
    p row
end
```

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html
- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: Why are you reading from ARGF? ARGV is more typical for CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CSV.parse(ARGF.read) do |row|
```

This worked, although it isn't lazy.

Answer (score 6):

If you want lazy you could try:

```
CSV.new(ARGF.file).each do |row|
  ...
end
```

Source:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#label-Wrap+an+IO+Object

Answer (score 4):

As it is said in http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#label-Wrap+an+IO+Object to use IO (like ARGF) you need to create a new cvs object:

```
csv = CSV.new(io, options)
```

An example like this one work fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#file : readCSV.rb
require "csv"
csv = CSV.new(ARGF, {:col_sep=>";", :headers=>:first_row})
csv.each do |line|
  p line.to_s
end
```

It can then be use in two ways:

1. `cat path/to/my.csv | ./readCSV.rb | less # for useless use of cat`
2. `./readCSV.rb < path/to/my.csv`
3. `./readCSV.rb path/to/my.csv | less`